# User able to mark only two Checkboxes in MSAccess 2013

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, limit

I've form which consist of four check boxes.I want end-user can mark only two check-boxes at a time. If he try to do so then he get the message box informing not more than two boxes selected at a time. Please help me to make it possible in MSAccess.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the beginning :

```
    Dim checks As Long

    Public Sub BUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

        Dim ch As Boolean

        ch = Screen.ActiveControl.Value

        Debug.Print ch

        If ch Then
            checks = checks + 1
        Else
            checks = checks - 1
        End If

        If checks > 2 Then
            Cancel = 1
            MsgBox "qwe"
        End If
    Debug.Print checks
    End Sub
```

and for each checkbox write this in `beforeupdate` event:

```
   BUpdate Cancel
```

This way will work until you will check some boxes and switch in design view and back.

Comment: I've added this code in BU event in form properties. But nothing happen!

Comment: this line `BUpdate Cancel` is to be inserted in `BeforeUpdate` event of each `CheckBox`